# Getting frequencies by fft_frequencies() function in Librosa

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft, librosa

I want to know what does the output array of [fft_frequencies()](http://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.fft_frequencies.html) function means.

I've heard that there are overtones corresponding each note,
but the output array seems to include only one frequency for each note per second.

I want to know, if the array already includes the overtones.

The code I wrote is below:

```
import librosa
from scipy import signal

y, sr = librosa.load('./data/dreamy.wav')
Nfft = 256
stft = librosa.stft(y, n_fft=Nfft, window=signal.windows.hamming)
freqs = librosa.fft_frequencies(sr=sr, n_fft=Nfft)

print(freqs)
```

And the result like this:

```
[    0.           86.1328125   172.265625    258.3984375   344.53125
   430.6640625   516.796875    602.9296875   689.0625      775.1953125
   861.328125    947.4609375  1033.59375    1119.7265625  1205.859375
   ... ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The [FFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) or [STFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform) does not produce *notes* like you can find them in [sheet music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheet_music#Musical_notation). Instead, it delivers the magnitude and phase for specific frequency bins. `fft_frequencies()` gives you these frequency bins in Hertz (Hz). Note that this has nothing to do with [overtones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overtone).

What you might be looking for is the [Constant-Q-Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant-Q_transform) (a.k.a. CQT), which can be configured to deliver something similar to "notes". However, it will contain overtones. If you are really after individual notes, you might want to try the [pYIN](https://www.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/%7Esimond/pub/2014/MauchDixon-PYIN-ICASSP2014.pdf) algorithm by Mauch and Dixon.

*librosa* happens to offer both a CQT and a pYIN implementation. You can find the docs [here](http://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.cqt.html) and [here](https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.pyin.html).